# AngularJS functions from factory service not responding (proper injection?)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-factory

I'm a student learning AngularJS and i can't seem to figure out why the functions from factory service is not responding in my view.  I think i'm calling the functions incorrectly but I've tried calling it so many ways that i'm not sure what is going on anymore.  Also, there's no error in console so i'm not sure what is happening. Appreciate any help and thanks for your time!

So I have my **factory todoService.js** here:

```
(function() {
    function TodoFact($firebaseArray) {
        var TodoFact = {};

        var todos = $firebaseArray(firebase.database().ref().child('/todo'));

        TodoFact.addTodo = function(){
            todos.$add(todo);
            todo.complete = false;
        };

        TodoFact.removeTodo = function(todo) { 
            var index = $scope.todos.indexOf(todo);
            $scope.todos.$remove(todo);
        };

        TodoFact.complete = function(todo) {
            todo.complete = true;
            todos.$save(todo);
        };

        var addFormShow = false;

        TodoFact.toggleForm = function() {
            addFormShow = addFormShow === false ? true : false;
        };

        return TodoFact;
    };

    angular
        .module('markOff')
        .factory('TodoFact', ['$firebaseArray', TodoFact]);   
})();
```

It is being injected into the **Controller TodoCtrl.js** here

```
(function() {
    function TodoCtrl(TodoFact) {
        this.todoFact = TodoFact;
    }
        angular
            .module('markOff')
            .controller('TodoCtrl', ['TodoFact', TodoCtrl]);
})();
```

I'm using ui-router and the routing has no issue.  I've also added scripts for todoService.js and controllers appropriately.

`<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>`

`<script src="/scripts/controllers/TodoCtrl.js"></script>`

`<script src="/scripts/services/todoService.js"></script>`

Here is a part of the view that i'm trying to solve.  Basically, on click event the element will toggle show / hide.

```
<div class="pull-right">
      <!-- Calling ToggleForm on click event, the element will show when addFormShow is false-->
      <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="todoFact.toggleForm()" ng-show="!todoFact.addFormShow"><span class="ion-loop"></span>Add</a>

      <!-- Calling ToggleForm on click event, ng-show if addFormShow is true -->
      <a class="btn btn-success" ng-click="todoFact.toggleForm()" ng-show="todoFact.addFormShow"><span class="ion-loop"></span>Cancel</a>
</div>
```

*** edit ***

This is how i'm routing to the view with controllers

```
(function() {
    function config($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $locationProvider
            .html5Mode({
                enabled: true,
                requireBase: false
            });
        $stateProvider
            .state('todo', {
                url: '/todo',
                controller: 'TodoCtrl as todo',
                templateUrl: '/templates/todo.html'
            });
    angular
        .module('markOff', ['firebase', 'ui.router'])
        .config(config);
})();
```

Comment: How are you calling `ngApp / ngController` in your view?

Comment: Are you sure you're declaring `ng-controller="TodoCtrl as todoFact"`? Because that's what you need for this to work.

Comment: @developer033  Sorry, i should be more clear on how i'm routing them.  So i have <html ng-app="markOff"> in my index.html.  In the body element of index.html, i'm using <ui-view></ui-view>.

Comment: @Aron The controller is working properly because the template is loading with appropriate url request.  I'm having trouble on how to call the functions from factory service.  Since the functions are stored in a todoFact Object, I was thinking todoFact.callme() but nothing was happening.

Comment: @hockmode if your controller alias is `todo` why are you expecting `todoFact.xyz` to do anything? `todoFact` is not the controller alias so won't do anything. What you _should_ do is `todo.callme();`.

Comment: `addShowForm` is a private variable of the `TodoFact` function. It is not available as a property of the `TodoFact` object. Thus  `todoFact.addFormShow` is undefined.

Comment: @Aron I've tried calling it that way too and it doesn't work.  But to clarify since my service is in `this.todoFact = TodoFact;`, shouldn't it be `todoFact.callme();`?

Comment: @georgeawg  Tried fixing it as you suggested.  I'm still not getting anything.

Comment: Everything was working fine when i had all the functions objects in controller file under `$scope.name` but i wanted to implement using factory service injection.  I'm doing it the way i've seen through google and what i've used before.  Although, It could be firebase since this is my first time using firebase... not sure where the error is

Comment: @hockmode you have a point, but in that case you need to call `todo.todoFact.callme();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the router uses "controllerAs" syntax:

```
   $stateProvider
        .state('todo', {
            url: '/todo',
            controller: 'TodoCtrl as todo',
            templateUrl: '/templates/todo.html'
        });
```

The template needs to prepend `todo` to the variables:

```
<div class="pull-right">
      <!-- Calling ToggleForm on click event, 
           the element will show when addFormShow is false-->
      <a ng-click="todo.todoFact.toggleForm()" 
         ng-show="!todo.todoFact.addFormShow">Add</a>

      <!-- Calling ToggleForm on click event, ng-show if addFormShow is true -->
      <a ng-click="todo.todoFact.toggleForm()" 
         ng-show="todo.todoFact.addFormShow">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

Also in the `TodoFact` factory, the `addFormShow` variable needs to be a public property of the `TodoFact` object.

```
    //var addFormShow = false;
    TodoFact.addFormShow = false;

    TodoFact.toggleForm = function() {
        //addFormShow = addFormShow === false ? true : false;
        TodoFact.addFormShow = TodoFact.addFormShow === false ? true : false;
    };

    return TodoFact;
```

Comment: Gotcha, will give it a go.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks a lot man!  It worked! I was missing `TodoFact.addFormShow` inside the `TodoFact.toggleForm`.  I had it as `addFormShow`.  Everything is working now.  Thanks!